# unable to change i3wm scaling

Tags: ubuntu, i3

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop. When it logs in I have to change the `scale for menu and title bars` to 2 in the screen display menu, so the system icons and text is not super tiny.  I want to start using the i3 window manager but have the same problem when I log in, the status bar along the bottom is so tiny as to be illegible.  How can I change this in i3wm?  I've tried changing it with `gsettings` but with no success, and the `gsettings` appear to be the same in i3wm as they are in Unity after I've rescaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [release notes](https://i3wm.org/downloads/RELEASE-NOTES-4.8.txt) for i3 4.8 cover this:

> Also very important for owners of HiDPI/“retina” displays is that i3 will now
>   respect your configured DPI and scale up its UI elements accordingly. Use
>   “xrandr --dpi 184” to set your dpi to 184, in case your setup does not figure
>   it out automatically. To get properly scaling fonts, we also changed the
>   default font from a bitmap font to a pango font (“DejaVu Sans Mono 8”).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: this only worked after I put it in a `.xsessionrc` file in my home dir.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple it turns out, I just needed to change the font size in my i3 config, from:

```
font pango:monospace 8
```

to:

```
font pango:monospace 24
```

EDIT: ok, I'm still learning! This is a little more complicated than I first thought.  I put @Wieland 's suggested command in a `~/.xsessionrc` file, which does now alter the status bar & title bar scaling and I have reverted the font size config in th i3 config file.